# List Comprehension in Rust

Tags: rust, list-comprehension

In python if I have an array like [2, 4, 6] I can do the following

```py
old_arr = [2, 4, 6]
new_arr = [x*2 for x in old_arr]
```

Is there a similar attribute in rust that will let me modify an array before returning it?

Comment: you probably look for `map`: ```let x = [1, 2, 3, 4]; let y = x.map(|x| x * 2);```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rust, [iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html) are used instead of comprehensions.

A very common pattern is `.iter().map(...).collect()`.

- `.iter()` creates an iterator from a iterable data structure
- `.map()` creates a new iterator over modified elements
- `.collect()` stores all the elements back in a data structure.

For example, to mimic your case:

```
fn main() {
    let old_arr = vec![2, 4, 6];
    let new_arr: Vec<i32> = old_arr.iter().map(|x| 2 * x).collect();
    println!("old_arr: {:?}", old_arr);
    println!("new_arr: {:?}", new_arr);
}
```

```
old_arr: [2, 4, 6]
new_arr: [4, 8, 12]
```

`|x| 2 * x` is a [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html).

Note that iterators in Rust are extremely fast, as they are mostly zero-cost abstractions.

---

In your special case, you could, however, also write:

```
fn main() {
    let old_arr = [2, 4, 6];
    let new_arr = old_arr.map(|x| 2 * x);
    println!("old_arr: {:?}", old_arr);
    println!("new_arr: {:?}", new_arr);
}
```

```
old_arr: [2, 4, 6]
new_arr: [4, 8, 12]
```

But that only works on arrays of constant size. For the general usecase, use vectors instead.